# Using ISNULL vs using COALESCE for checking a specific condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coalesce, isnull

I know that multiple parameters can be passed to `COALESCE`, but  when you want to to 
check just one expression to see if it doesn't exist, do you use a default or is it a better practice to use `ISNULL` instead?

Is there any performance gain between the two?

Comment: The [COALESCE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) has this note: ISNULL and COALESCE though equivalent, can behave differently. An expression involving ISNULL with non-null parameters is considered to be NOT NULL, while expressions involving COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL...

Comment: `ISNULL` will also coerce the result to the datatype of the first expression [as illustrated here](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/01/21/difference-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx)

Comment: This article spells out the differences quite well... http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

Comment: This is a good article as well... http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[This problem reported on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546437/coalesce-subquery-1-may-return-null#details) reveals some differences between `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`:

> an early part of our processing rewrites `COALESCE( expression1, expression2 )` as `CASE WHEN expression1 IS NOT NULL THEN expression1 ELSE expression2 END`. In [this example]:
>
> ```
> COALESCE ( ( SELECT Nullable
>              FROM Demo
>              WHERE SomeCol = 1 ), 1 )
> ```
>
> we generate:
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE
>           WHEN (SELECT Nullable FROM Demo WHERE SomeCol = 1) IS NOT NULL
>           THEN (SELECT Nullable FROM Demo WHERE SomeCol = 1)
>           ELSE 1
>        END
> ```
>
> Later stages of query processing don't understand that the two subqueries were originally the same expression, so they execute the subquery twice...
>
> One workaround, though I hate to suggest it, is to change `COALESCE` to `ISNULL`, since the latter doesn't duplicate the subquery.

Comment: quick question, if you have 3 values, like coalesce(expression1, expression2, expression3, 1), where those 'expressions' are actually select statements, would it then make sense to actual do nested isnull statements? ie isnull(expression1, isnull(expression2, isnull(expression3, 1)))

Answer (score 28):

I think not, but COALESCE is in the SQL '92 standard and supported by more different databases. If you go for portability, don't use ISNULL.

Comment: @AaronAnodide MySQL uses `ifnull`, sql server `isnull`.

Comment: Oracle's alternative to `COALESCE` is `NVL`. So, the point of COALESCE being standard is valid, even if its implementation details differ among databases.

Answer (score 13):

In [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) you can have multiple expressions, where as in [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) you can check only one expression

```
COALESCE ( expression [ ,...n ] ) 

ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

Answer (score 10):

Worth mentioning is that the type handling between the two can also make a difference (see [this related answer item (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828687/538763)).

Say a query tries to use a shortcut for writing null comparison:

```
select * from SomeTable
 where IsNull(SomeNullableBitField, -1) != IsNull(SomeOtherNullableBitField, -1);
```

which is different than

```
select * from SomeTable
 where coalesce(SomeNullableBitField, -1) != coalesce(SomeOtherNullableBitField, -1);
```

Because in the first case, the IsNull() forces the type to be a bit (so -1 is converted to true) whereas the second case will promote both to an int.

```
with input as 
(
  select convert(bit, 1) as BitOn,      
         convert(bit, 0) as BitOff,
         convert(bit, null) as BitNull
)
select BitOn, 
       BitOff,
       BitNull,
       IsNull(BitOn, -1) IsNullBitOn,         -- true
       IsNull(BitOff, -1) IsNullBitOff,       -- false
       IsNull(BitNull, -1) IsNullBitNull,     -- true, converts the -1 to bit
       coalesce(BitOn, -1) CoalesceBitOn,     -- 1
       coalesce(BitOff, -1) CoalesceBitOff,   -- 0       
       coalesce(BitNull, -1) CoalesceBitNull  -- -1
  from input;
```

There is a similar comment/link (@Martin Smith) on the question itself.

Answer (score 10):

One major thing that I don't see explicitly indicated is that `ISNULL`'s output type is similar to the first expression but with `COALESCE` it returns the datatype of value of highest precedence.

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(3) = NULL
DECLARE @Y VARCHAR(10) = '123456789'
/* The datatype returned is similar to X, or the first expression*/
SELECT ISNULL(@X, @Y) ---> Output is '123'
/* The datatype returned is similar to Y, or to the value of highest precedence*/
SELECT COALESCE(@X, @Y) ---> Output is '123456789'
```

Comment: It's not a matter of first vs second/Nth expression. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828641/sql-difference-between-coalesce-and-isnull/18828687#18828687): `ISNULL uses the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE follows the CASE expression rules and returns the data type of value with the highest precedence.`

Answer (score 9):

The `NULL` and `COALESCE` are not always interchangeable. It deserves to know their differences in order to know when its better to use the one over the other:

[image]

The table above is comparison between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` from `Exam Ref 70-761 Querying Data with Transact-SQL` book written by Itzik Ben-Gan.

---

1. Number of supported parameters - `2` for `ISNULL` vs `>2` when using `COALESCE`
2. `ISNULL` is proprietary T-SQL feature and `COALESCE` is ISO/ANSI SQL standard
3. The data type of the result is important. After reading notes in the table above, check the following cases:

   ```
   DECLARE @x VARCHAR(3)  = NULL
          ,@y VARCHAR(10) = '1234567890';

   SELECT ISNULL(@x, @y) AS [ISNULL], COALESCE(@x, @y) AS [COALESCE];
   ```

   [image]

   The `ISNULL` is getting the data type of the first argument as it is the not 
   `NULL` literal. It is `VARCHAR(3)` and is a result, the second argument data 
   is cut to match it. With `COALESCE` the data type if highest precedence is 
   used.

   ```
   DECLARE @x VARCHAR(8)  = '123x5'
          ,@y INT = 123;

   SELECT ISNULL(@x, @y) AS [ISNULL];
   SELECT COALESCE(@x, @y) AS [COALESCE];
   ```

   [image]

   [image]

   The `ISNULL` is returning the data type of first argument, while in 
   `COALESCE` we are getting error, as the `INT` has highest precedence and the 
   conversion of the first argument value to `INT` fails.
4. The nullability of the result can be important, too. For, example:

   ```
   DECLARE @x VARCHAR(3) = NULL
          ,@y VARCHAR(3) = NULL;

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[DataSource01];

   SELECT ISNULL(10, 20) AS [C1]
         ,ISNULL(@x, 'text') AS [C2]
         ,ISNULL(@x, @y) AS [C3]
   INTO [dbo].[DataSource01];

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[DataSource02];

   SELECT COALESCE(10, 20) AS [C1]
         ,COALESCE(@x, 'text') AS [C2]
         ,COALESCE(@x, @y) AS [C3]
   INTO [dbo].[DataSource02];
   ```

   Let's check the `Nullable` property of each column:

   [image]

   [image]

   Using `COALESCE` we have a `NOT NULL` property of column set to `Yes`, only 
   when all of the inputs are non null-able.
5. According to the SQL standard, the `COALESCE` expression is translated to:

   ```
   CASE WHEN (<subquery>) IS NOT NULL THEN (<subquery>) ELSE 0 END
   ```

   > If the result of the execution of the subquery in the WHEN clause isn’t 
   >     NULL, SQL Server executes it a second time in the THEN clause.
   >   In other words, in such a case it executes it twice. Only if the
   >   result of the execution in the WHEN clause is NULL, SQL Server doesn’t
   >   execute the subquery again, rather returns the ELSE expression. So
   >   when using subqueries, the ISNULL function has a performance
   >   advantage.

Answer (score 3):

This explanation gives clear about coalesce vs isnull

The COALESCE function in SQL returns the first non-NULL expression among its arguments. The syntax for COALESCE is as follows:

```
 COALESCE ("expression 1", "expressions 2", ...)
```

It is the same as the following CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE ("column_name")
  WHEN "expression 1 is not NULL" THEN "expression 1"
  WHEN "expression 2 is not NULL" THEN "expression 2"
  ...
  [ELSE "NULL"]
  END
FROM "table_name";
```

In SQL Server, the ISNULL( ) function is used to replace NULL value with another value.

```
select CountryName = ISNULL("columnname", 'INDIA') from Countries
```

Coalesce return first non null expression where as isnull() is used to replace null value with our desired value.

COALESCE is a part of ANSI standards and are available in almost all databases.

when deciding between ISNULL v COALESCE there parameters has to be taken care off:

1. COALESCE determines the type of the output based on data type precedence where as With ISNULL, the data type is not influenced by data type precedence.
2. Consider following sql statements

   ```
   DECLARE @c5 VARCHAR(5);
   SELECT 'COALESCE', COALESCE(@c5, 'longer name')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ISNULL',   ISNULL(@c5,   'longer name');
   ```

Results:

```
COALESCE longer name
ISNULL   longe
```

This happens because ISNULL takes the data type of the first argument, while COALESCE inspects all of the elements and chooses the best fit (in this case, VARCHAR(11))

For more detailed explanation on deciding between COALESCE vs ISNULL check this:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Where there is only one null condition, `ISNULL` will have less overhead. The difference is probably negligible, though.

Comment: Do you have any support for the claim that there is less overhead with `ISNULL`?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: There are two areas where `COALESCE` would introduce more overhead when used interchangeably. First, `ISNULL` deals with a fixed number of inputs, where `COALESCE` is designated to work with any number of inputs. Secondly, `COALESCE` is configured to return the data type of the expression with the highest data type precedence, whereas `ISNULL` returns the same type as the `check_expression`. As I said above, in later versions of SQL Server the difference is probably negligible, but strictly speaking there is still overhead.

Answer (score -2):

In COALESCE one can use multiple expressions, It will return value which is not a null and occurs first... for example

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT, @Value2 INT, @Value3 INT, @Value4 INT
SELECT @Value2 = 2, @Value4 = 4
SELECT COALESCE(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4)
SELECT COALESCE(@Value1, @Value4, @Value3, @Value2)
```

And in ISNULL if expression null it will return second parameter provided, and of course you can check only for one expression...

So if want check multiple expression and select first not null among them, then use coalesce otherwise go for ISNULL

Comment: OP stated that they were aware of the ability of COALESCE to handle multiple parameters, the question is about the specific case when there are only two.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake please read complete answer... I read question and I request you read my answer completely... Its very easy to over look some point and down vote it