# SQL Create Table [Default]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Can I specify DEFAULT to get the exact value of a column?

I am creating a `Serial` table, with range, some has `From` and `To` and some are just singular.

Therefore I have two columns: `[Serial_Fr]` & `[Serial_To]`

If I insert `Serial_Fr` only, I want to populate `Serial_To = Serial_Fr`.

How do I do that? Or should I use triggers and just set default = '', in doing this I think it will cause a strain when I have millions of serials.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: MSSQL Sorry, was in a rush typing.

Comment: You'd have to use a trigger but you also could just leave it NULL and deal with it when querying the table. Something like `BETWEEN Serial_Fr AND ISNULL(Serial_To, Serial_Fr)`

Comment: thats great! but isnt NULL a bad thing in Normalization? or am I interpreting normalization wrong..

Comment: @Sid - `NULL` definitely isn't a bad thing. Consider a table containing user information where it's perfectly possible to not know the age *(stretching it a bit here but hope you'll get the point:))*. Without `NULL`, you have to *come up with some value* to represent the unknown age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a View which is

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT 
  Serial_Fr,
  Serial_To =  COALESCE(Serial_To,Serial_Fr)
FROM MyTable
```

Or this could be done in a `Stored Procedure`

But what is wrong with leaving some of the entries in `Serial_To` as `NULL` ?

---

**Edit**

`ISNULL` is `T-sql` : `COALESCE` is 92 standard sql. There is a good discussion of the subtle differences between these functions [HERE ON SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/isnull-vs-coalesce)

Martin Smith also refers to an article which has this interesting example that illustrates a difference:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @first VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @second VARCHAR(4)

SELECT @first = ISNULL(@test, 'test')
SELECT @second = COALESCE(@test, 'test')

PRINT @first
PRINT @second
```

Comment: I did not get this solution...sorry. Sometimes I populate Serial From then Serial To differently. not always the same

Comment: ok - just the View section of the solution will work - although I need to amend it slightly

Comment: @Sid did you try creating a View?

Comment: Yes I tried creating a View, but I skipped on this part as to we don't know yet if NULL is acceptable or not. thanks for this. COALESCE is the one I am looking for