# TSQL/ SSIS: Set column to one of two columns, whichever is not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Thanks for looking, this is probably a simple question.

I have a table, tableA with three columns: tableID, id_1, and id_2

In each row, either id_1 or id_2 is populated with an integer.
I want to go through each row and set the tableID to either id_1 or id_2, whichever is not null.

I'm doing this in SSIS with a small dataset, probably less than 20 records. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `COALESCE`? Or are you asking how to perform an `UPDATE`?

Comment: I need to do an UPDATE, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in its simplest form:

`update tableA
set tableID = isnull(id_1,id_2)`

Thats assuming that id_1 will always be null if id_2 has a value (which is what you say)

EDIT: a bit more sensible statement:

```
update tableA set tableID = isnull(id_1,id_2) where tableID is null
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to do this on a row by row basis, so could I run this in SSIS as an OLE DB command? And yes, one of the ids will(or should!) be NULL.

Comment: just executing this command once on the table will update all rows in the table, so you could just stick that inside the "Execute SQL" task in the design planner ;)

Comment: Even better, I greatly appreciate the wisdom!

Comment: `COALESCE` is standard SQL and handles two or more parameters.  `ISNULL` is non-standard and is limited to two parameters. Some additional information on `ISNULL` vs. `COALESCE` is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/using-isnull-vs-using-coalesce-for-checking-a-specific-condtion).