# Can SQL Case statement be used to select a database column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT sets.set_id, responses.Question_Id, replies.reply_text, responses.Response
FROM response_sets AS sets
INNER JOIN responses AS responses ON sets.set_id = responses.set_id
INNER JOIN replies AS replies ON replies.reply_id = responses.reply_id
WHERE sets.Sctn_Id_Code IN ('668283', '664524')
```

A partial result:

[image]

I want to replace the `reply_text` and response columns with one column that will have the value of the response if it isn't null and the reply text value otherwise.  I'm not sure if this can be done with a case statement, at least nothing I've dug up leads me to think that I can.  Am I incorrect in assuming this?

Comment: Replace this: `replies.reply_text, responses.Response` with `COALESCE(responses.Response, replies.reply_text) AS AliasName`

Comment: `sets` is a future sQL Server is a reserved word, so it is not a good name for an identifier.

Comment: Duly noted and changed Gordon.  Thanks DMason and Jeff for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a case statement, but `COALESCE` would be easier:

```
Select sets.set_id, responses.Question_Id, COALESCE(responses.Response, replies.reply_text)
From response_sets as sets
inner join responses as responses on sets.set_id = responses.set_id
inner join replies as replies on replies.reply_id = responses.reply_id
where sets.Sctn_Id_Code in ('668283', '664524')
```

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) allows you to list two or more expressions, and takes the first one that isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ISNULL(responses.Response, replies.reply_text)` or `COALESCE` also works.  Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/using-isnull-vs-using-coalesce-for-checking-a-specific-condtion) for more information and examples.  This [article dives](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) deeper into `ISNULL` vs `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

This is from an Oracle select statement, but if it works in Oracle, it's possible it will also work in SQL Server (with some syntax changes):

```
, (case when bseg1.start_dt is null then bseg2.start_dt else bseg1.start_dt end) bseg_startdt
```

This is selecting the second start date when the first is null.

Specific SQL Server answers will be a better option, of course.