# case when in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table when contains who's two column contains data/null , i want to capture only rows which is not null.

example of t1

```
Application_channel | reason_for_joining
            call    | null
            null    | do not wish to provide
            null    | null
```

I want output as

```
Status
 call
 do not wish to provide
```

query i wrote is somthing like:-

```
select case 
when reason_for_joining is null and application_channel is not null then       application_channel
when application_channel is null and reason_for_joining is not null then 
reason_for_joining else application_channel end as status
from t1
```

the problem is its also taking null when both the column has null value which i dont want. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hint : `COALESCE()` with `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @YogeshSharma what's the difference between `COALESCE()` and `ISNULL()`?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto. . . For instance i would say `COALESCE()` is ANSI SQL Function which works almost in all `DBMS`, while `ISNULL()` is only `SQL Server` specific, apart from that it functionally behaves different.

Comment: And in `SQL Server`?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto COALESCE basically translates to CASE expression and ISNULL is a built-in implemented in the database engine. Both ISNULL and COALESCE can be used to get the same results but there are some differences.                                           1. Data type determination of the resulting expression - ISNULL uses the first parameter type, COALESCE follows the CASE expression rules and returns type of value with highest precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He also wanted to filter those that are empty, so it would be:

```
select coalesce(Application_channel, reason_for_joining) as status
from t1
where coalesce(Application_channel, reason_for_joining) is not null
```

Alternatively you could also filter like this:

```
WHERE Application_channel IS NOT NULL OR reason_for_joining IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: von spickzak, thanks buddy, i have used the atternative one, and it worked . Much appreciated your help. i have also tried coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

You want `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(Application_channel, reason_for_joining) as status
from t1
```

Comment: thanks brother Gordon. i have used WHERE Application_channel IS NOT NULL OR reason_for_joining IS NOT NULL seems to fix my issue. any difference between coalesce and is not null?

Comment: Basically ISNULL takes only two arguments while COALESCE takes multiple arguments (it returns the first non-NULL). For more details see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/using-isnull-vs-using-coalesce-for-checking-a-specific-condition

Answer (score 0):

Is case of two parameter ISNULL also do same work

```
select ISNULL('call',null),isnull(null,'do not')
```

so in you query

```
select ISNULL(Application_channel, reason_for_joining) as status
from t1
where ISNULL(Application_channel, reason_for_joining) is not null
```